# Comparing two style files for if there are common x:key exist

Tags: xaml, text-comparison

My problem is not directly programmatic,

I'm working on a project have 5 resource dictionary . I'm not sure if same keys are used in these rd's.

i.e. rd1.xaml contains x:key="backgroundcolor" and rd2.xaml also.

In Expression Blend no error appear interestingly.

Anyway is there any of finding common keys between files?

```
           <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#d0157820" x:Key="muddyBrush"/>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="rd1.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="rd2.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="rd3.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="rd4.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="rd5.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
           </Application.Resources>
```